# Broken Fedora install: can't read superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p4

Tags: fedora, boot, partition, dual-boot, opensuse

I honestly don't know how this happened, as far is I can tell I was only using openSUSE Tumbleweed (my first distro), but at some point I couldn't boot on Fedora (my second distro) anymore.

I can't really make sense of the logs and errors, so here are some bits of information, and feel free to ask for more:

The mount tree of a correctly booted Fedora was (when it still worked):

- `/dev/nvme0n1p1` mounted on `/boot/efi`
- `/dev/nvme0n1p2` mounted on `/boot`
- `/dev/nvme0n1p4` mounted on `/`
- and `swapon` `/dev/nvme0n1p3`.

I'm currently running openSUSE Tumbleweed, on `/dev/sda1` (and there's a `/dev/sda2` for swap).These are all my partitions, on my two disks.

The easiest way to spot the problem is to do this in openSUSE:

```
> sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p4 /mnt
mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p4.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

The other way is to boot on Fedora, and look for error once I get to the repair console. I also did that, and here's the last few lines of the log (`rdsosreport.txt`):

```
[    5.974350] gamestation systemd[1]: Mounting sysroot.mount - /sysroot...
[    5.984799] gamestation kernel: BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p4): using crc32c (crc32c-intel) checksum algorithm
[    5.984820] gamestation kernel: BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p4): using free space tree
[    6.016320] gamestation kernel: BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p4): enabling ssd optimizations
[    6.016329] gamestation kernel: BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p4): auto enabling async discard
[    6.016333] gamestation kernel: BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p4): start tree-log replay
[    6.016557] gamestation kernel: BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p4): parent transid verify failed on logical 75616649216 mirror 1 wanted 3774 found 3773
[    6.016741] gamestation kernel: BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p4): parent transid verify failed on logical 75616649216 mirror 2 wanted 3774 found 3773
[    6.016755] gamestation kernel: BTRFS warning (device nvme0n1p4): failed to read log tree
[    6.019725] gamestation mount[509]: mount: /sysroot: can't read superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p4.
[    6.019725] gamestation mount[509]:        dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
[    6.019962] gamestation kernel: BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p4): open_ctree failed
[    6.020361] gamestation systemd[1]: sysroot.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
[    6.020489] gamestation systemd[1]: sysroot.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[    6.027539] gamestation systemd[1]: Failed to mount sysroot.mount - /sysroot.
[    6.027691] gamestation systemd[1]: Dependency failed for initrd-root-fs.target - Initrd Root File System.
[    6.027749] gamestation systemd[1]: Dependency failed for initrd-parse-etc.service - Mountpoints Configured in the Real Root.
[    6.027796] gamestation systemd[1]: initrd-parse-etc.service: Job initrd-parse-etc.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[    6.027841] gamestation systemd[1]: initrd-parse-etc.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
[    6.028086] gamestation systemd[1]: initrd-root-fs.target: Job initrd-root-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[    6.028137] gamestation systemd[1]: initrd-root-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
[    6.028698] gamestation systemd[1]: Stopped target basic.target - Basic System.
[    6.028859] gamestation systemd[1]: Reached target initrd-fs.target - Initrd File Systems.
[    6.028909] gamestation systemd[1]: Stopped target sysinit.target - System Initialization.
[    6.028965] gamestation systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    6.039256] gamestation systemd[1]: Stopped dracut-initqueue.service - dracut initqueue hook.
[    6.039569] gamestation systemd[1]: dracut-pre-udev.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    6.048075] gamestation systemd[1]: Stopped dracut-pre-udev.service - dracut pre-udev hook.
[    6.048196] gamestation systemd[1]: dracut-cmdline.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    6.054063] gamestation systemd[1]: Stopped dracut-cmdline.service - dracut cmdline hook.
[    6.054162] gamestation systemd[1]: dracut-cmdline-ask.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    6.060064] gamestation systemd[1]: Stopped dracut-cmdline-ask.service - dracut ask for additional cmdline parameters.
[    6.070201] gamestation systemd[1]: Started emergency.service - Emergency Shell.
[    6.070605] gamestation systemd[1]: Reached target emergency.target - Emergency Mode.
[    6.070690] gamestation systemd[1]: Startup finished in 9.729s (firmware) + 7.721s (loader) + 1.540s (kernel) + 0 (initrd) + 4.529s (userspace) = 23.521s.
[    6.087557] gamestation systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 426 (plymouthd).
[    6.100118] gamestation systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 426 (plymouthd).
```

And finally the end of the output of `dmesg`:

```
[   17.184467] sddm-greeter[1856]: memfd_create() called without MFD_EXEC or MFD_NOEXEC_SEAL set
[   22.770519] wlp1s0: authenticate with 7c:16:89:d7:b9:b4
[   22.817934] wlp1s0: send auth to 7c:16:89:d7:b9:b4 (try 1/3)
[   22.818996] wlp1s0: authenticated
[   22.823705] wlp1s0: associate with 7c:16:89:d7:b9:b4 (try 1/3)
[   22.826980] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 7c:16:89:d7:b9:b4 (capab=0x511 status=0 aid=117)
[   22.830069] wlp1s0: associated
[   22.830376] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x80fa
[   22.830383] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   22.830387] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   22.830391] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[   22.830395] ath: Country alpha2 being used: FR
[   22.830400] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[   22.830404] ath: regdomain 0x80fa dynamically updated by country element
[   22.873404] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 7c:16:89:d7:b9:b4
[   31.647894] warning: `kded5' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
[   32.940643] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   32.940654] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   32.940660] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  810.731875] BTRFS info (device sda1): qgroup scan paused
[  845.654708] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

So that's where I am. I have run `fsck` as root on all four partitions, buto only for `dev/nvme0n1p2` (`/boot`) did I get a real output. For `/dev/nvmesd4`, the only output was `fsck some-version-number`, and I still have this superblock problem.

Can someone help? (I would really appreciate if I could get my Fedora back quickly, as I have a few things I need it for...)

Thanks!

---

*EDIT*: I finally found out that the right tool to rearrange my partition was `btrfs` or `btrfs filesystem`. So I made some research online, tried out some commands with it, and now everything works. I don't remember precisely (and I can't check my TW's history right now), but I think I ran:

- `sudo btrfs rescue super-recover -v /dev/nvme0n1p4`;
- `sudo btrfs rescue zero-log /dev/nvme0n1p4`
  I don't know if these are the exact commands I used, but once you know this I thing it's pretty straightforward to Google what you need.

I hope this can be helpful to someone one day!